¿Cómo dockerizar vite de un proyecto laravel inertia?
Tengo una aplicacion laravel inertial con vuejs y esta aplicacion esta dockerizada en un contenedor con apache que tiene todo lo necesario aparte tengo una imagen de mysql corriendo tambien en otro contenedor para conectar la app con la base de datos. Ademas tengo que correr en mi maquina un npm install y despes un npm run dev para correr el front con vite. Me gustaria no tener que instalar node y npm en mi maquina si no tambien contenerizar esa parte. Lo intente varias veces pero no tuve exito
Esta es mi structura de carpetas
LaravelVueInertial/
├── conf
├── docker-compose.yaml
├── dump
├── php
│   └── Dockerfile
└── src
    ├── app
    ├── artisan
    ├── bootstrap
    ├── composer.json
    ├── composer.lock
    ├── config
    ├── database
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── jsconfig.json
    ├── package.json
    ├── phpunit.xml
    ├── postcss.config.js
    ├── public
    ├── README.md
    ├── resources
    ├── routes
    ├── storage
    ├── tailwind.config.js
    ├── tests
    ├── vendor
    └── vite.config.js

Este es mi docker compose donde defino tres servicios, uno para el laravel, uno para db y otro que es el que intento realizar para el vite
services:
    php:
        build:
            context: ./php
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        container_name: crm
        volumes:
            - ./src:/var/www/html/
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        links:
            - mysql
            - vite
        networks:
            - default
    mysql:
        image: mysql
        container_name: mysql
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: secret
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
        volumes:
            - persistent:/var/lib/mysql
        networks:
            - default
    vite:
        build:
            context: ./src
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        container_name: vite
        volumes:
            - ./src:/app
        ports:
            - "5173:5173"
        networks:
            - default

networks:
    default:

volumes:
  persistent:

La imagen de php y mysql se contruyen exitosamente pero la de vite que intento construir termina inmediatamente mostrandme lo siguiente
vite   | 
vite   | > dev
vite   | > vite
vite   | 
vite   | sh: 1: vite: not found
vite exited with code 127

El cotenido del dockerfile que esta dentro de src es el siguiente
# Use the official Node.js image as base
FROM node:latest

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json (if available) from src directory
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of the application code from src directory
COPY . .

# Expose the port that the application will run on
EXPOSE 5173

# Command to run the application
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]

No tengo tanta experiencia en docker pero fue lo que se me ocurrio pero llevo tiempo en lo mismo sin ningun resultado distinto.
